# UdpClient doesn't receive multicast traffic upon connection

Tags: c#, windows, udp, multicast

I'm using a `UdpClient` to receive and send multicast traffic, but I'm having a problem when a new network interface becomes operational while the application is up and running.

The `UdpClient` is created in my application when the interface becomes operational (plug in network cable raises [NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)), it binds to the static IP of the interface, and the expected IGMP packets are visible in wireshark on that interface, but the `UdpClient` instance never reports there is any data available.

The issue also appears to be present if you create the `UdpClient` before the cable is connected.

I've tried setting `SocketOptionName.MulticastInterface`, but that should only concern *sending* multicast traffic, not receiving...  Example for this here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318911

Here is a console app that exhibits this issue.  While this app is running, I connect the Ethernet cable and Wireshark shows the IGMP join group packets from this app, and incoming multicast traffic from another computer.  If I have the cable already plugged in and start the app, it receives all of the traffic I expect.

```
class Program
{
    static UdpClient udpClient;

    static IPAddress bindAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.101.220");
    static IPAddress groupListenAddress = IPAddress.Parse("239.255.0.1");
    static int port = 9999;

    static bool shouldRun = true;
    static Thread thread;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        udpClient = new UdpClient();
        udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastLoopback, true);

        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(bindAddress, port);
        udpClient.Client.Bind(localEndPoint);

        udpClient.JoinMulticastGroup(groupListenAddress);

        thread = new Thread(runThread);
        thread.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        shouldRun = false;
        thread.Join(100);
    }

    private static void runThread(object obj)
    {
        while (shouldRun)
        {
            if (udpClient.Available > 0)
            {
                IPEndPoint endPoint = null;
                byte[] buffer = udpClient.Receive(ref endPoint);
                Console.WriteLine("Received Message from: {0} Length: {1}", endPoint, buffer.Length);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Am I understanding this correct? You have a network interface which has the static IP 192.168.101.220. Then you plug in the cable while the application is running.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  The application is already running and then the network cable is plugged in.  The IGMP packets are then sent, but the UdpClient never receives any data.  If you run the app after the cable is connected, data is received.

Comment: I'm not an expert on multicast or something like that, but doesn't your application has to 'join' the multicast group of the network of the new interface when it goes online?

Comment: You are right, the JoinMulticastGroup method sends an IGMP packet - in this case, it is not sending it until the network comes online - but I definitely see it in Wireshark once connected.

Comment: I did a little test setup and couldn't see an IGMP package from my pc (which runs the code above). But I'm gonna try it again tomorrow (hopefully with the correct IP filter :).

Answer (score 1):

Note that IGMP messages are sent by your host OS, not by your application. If the OS sees a join for a multicast address for the first time it will send out IGMP messages. If another process wants to join the same address as well, new IGMP message may or may not be sent.

Also all kinds of network components (in particular routers, but also Powerline adapters use IGMP snooping to find out where to send multicast traffic, and they often get it wrong. There are two incompatible versions of IGMP and some devices support only one version and some translate between versions in a strange way. This is a big mess.

To make it all really horrible, most devices, including your local host OS, have a time dependent behavior. This makes analyzing problems really difficult since you can never draw hard conclusions, because at the moment it may work just by chance.

Independent of IGMP, the bind() statement is confusing for UDP. On Linux bindign to an IP address will *filter* all incoming UDP packets and you will only receive packets going to this specific IP address. To receive multicast traffic on Linux you usually have to bind to 0.0.0.0. But I assume you are using Windows, where binding to an IP address of a local adapter is the right thing. Then you will receive mutilcast traffic going to this adapter.

Comment: I am using Windows, but I'm not receiving the multicast traffic in this situation.  Its interesting about why this multicast is hard to get right, I wasn't aware of a lot of this.  Thanks!